LuaLaTeX/Tabularray - SetCell code taking up all columns seems to not work when had by itself
I'm trying to make my resume in LaTeX (trying to put my skills to the test) that has tabularray code that doesn't seem to work when I want SetCell to take up all columns and only have that.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c] X[c] X[c]}, % specify column widths
  width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
}
\SetCell[c=3]{c} Forms Of Contact \& Address \\
gmail@gmail.com & (777) 777 7777  & Earth \\
\end{tblr}

 \section{\LARGE{About Me}}

\noindent \begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X X X}, % specify column widths
  width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
  hspan = minimal,
}
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tblr}

 \section{\LARGE{Work Experience}}

\noindent \begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
  width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
  hspan = minimal,
}
  Elementary School Custodian (Hogwarts Elementary School) & & September 4909 - May 4912 \\
  \SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[2] \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

The problem that comes with this code is that the second table produces an error, and the error goes away when I delete the second table.
What gives? Why does that code work when I add additional content like in the other tables but not when I simply want what I am trying to achieve with the second row? In Overleaf it will compile anyway and give me the result that I expect, but am I using the wrong code? It would be of immense

Your problem is not specific to \luaLaTeX, it appear at pdfLaTeX too. tabularray in contrary to clasic tables packages require, that you need at multicolumn cells to write all ampersands for spanned columns. For example, instead of
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[2]          \\ 

you should write
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[2]  &    &   \\

Complete MWE, where I omit not neccessary declaration for table, is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor = black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] X[c] X[c]}, % specify column widths
                      hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
                      }
\SetCell[c=3]{c} Forms Of Contact \& Address    
    &                   &               \\
\href{mailto:gmail@gmail.com}{gmail@gmail.com} 
    &   (777) 777 7777  & Earth         \\
\end{tblr}

 \section{\LARGE{About Me}}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X X X}, % specify column widths
                      hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
                      hspan = minimal,
                     }
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[1] 
    &                   &               \\
\end{tblr}

 \section{\LARGE{Work Experience}}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
                      hlines, % vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
                      hspan = minimal,
                     }
  Elementary School Custodian (Hogwarts Elementary School) 
    &   & September 4909 - May 4912 \\
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[2] 
    &   &                           \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


The same result you can obtain by using pdfLaTeX, which is fatter tha LuaLaTeX. For e-mail I add hyperref package. So, it is now clickable. Color for email you can change to one which you may more liked.
